# Sending E-mail from the client

Tags: vb.net, client, account, email

hi guys i need some help the vb.net. my problem is that i have got an formular with "name" "password" "e-mail" and some other.... i want that the client file in his for example name and i want to recieve an e-mail at my e-emil acc. Can somebody help my please?

Comment: Are you wanting the email to be sent through the user's Email Client (outlook, etc) or behind the scenes automatically using SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you are asking, but you should be able to use the MailMessage class in System.Net.Mail to send the emails.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx